# AS3 - Flash to AIR - ExternalInterface

Tags: actionscript-3, air, externalinterface

I have a flash project that I am trying to convert to Adobe AIR to be compatible with steam. The flash project uses ExternalInterface calls into Javascript that embeds the swf that are essential to the app (PHP logins, Facebook interactions, etc).

What are my options for getting around a lack of ExternalInterface when using Adobe AIR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to re-implement all this features (login, social network integration) without ExternalInterface. I think, you need to use Steam API for much part of this.

Comment: Hey Crabar, thanks for the response. I am currently looking into HtmlLoader to load the html that also loads my embedded SWF. Not sure if this will be a dead end or not (would be great if adobe air could just be a wrapper that loads my webpage and swf)

Comment: In my opinion, it's not very good way. First of all, in this solution may be some restriction problems (in HtmlLoader for example). And second, solution with native steam api support will much more flexible and closer to steam players. But it just my opinion, maybe your way will simpler.